# How do I save a result of a calculated select in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I save a result of a calculated select in a column? I want to save(write it) the result of that multiplication in a column of table one like table1.total

```
SELECT table1.quantity * table2.price AS result
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.code = table2.code
```

Comment: Create the column (alter table statement) and update the relevant records (update statement). The official docs have everything you need.

Comment: please explain what exactly do you mean by `save the result`

Comment: There's something called a computed column that might be relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just mean this:

```
UPDATE table1 SET total = table1.quantity * table2.price
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.code = table2.code
```

See example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0fa1571e81a47e6cd9e2b6f4e3c1914a)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary table:

```
SELECT table1.quantity * table2.price AS result INTO #Temp
    FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.code = table2.code
```

The table '#Temp' will be removed after connection closed.

For more information, check this url:https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-temporary-tables/

Comment: I think this is another reasonable interpretation of the question.